# Azure Function App: Can I put maxConcurrentSessions settings in Application settings Configuration like service bus configuration

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have below below settings `host.json` for `maxConcurrentSessions` for Azure Function app service bus trigger.

```json
"extensions": {
  "serviceBus": {
    "sessionHandlerOptions": {
      "autoComplete": false,
      "maxConcurrentSessions": 100
    }
  }
}
```

Can I set this host json configuration Function App configuration application settings like service bus connection string? if Yes, how?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#override-hostjson-values), you can override settings defined in the `host.json` using `appsettings`:

> There may be instances where you wish to configure or modify specific settings in a host.json file for a specific environment, without changing the host.json file itself. You can override specific host.json values by creating an equivalent value as an application setting. When the runtime finds an application setting in the format `AzureFunctionsJobHost__path__to__setting`, it overrides the equivalent host.json setting located at `path.to.setting` in the JSON. When expressed as an application setting, the dot (`.`) used to indicate JSON hierarchy is replaced by a double underscore (`__`).

So in you case defining an appsetting `AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensions__serviceBus__sessionHandlerOptions__maxConcurrentSessions` will do the trick.

Comment: Excellent!!! Thanks @Thomas. Appreciate your help.